# Anaconda (Python) + Cmder (Clink) on Windows - Unify Dueling Custom Prompts

Tags: batch-file, lua, command-prompt, anaconda, conda

If you run Anaconda on windows, you have an [`activate.bat`](https://github.com/conda/conda/blob/master/bin/activate.bat) file which concludes with this line to put your current conda env on the prompt:

```
set PROMPT=[%CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV%] $P$G
```

If you run cmder on windows, there is a [nice lua script](https://github.com/bliker/cmder/blob/master/config/prompt.lua) to customize your prompt:

```
function lambda_prompt_filter()
    clink.prompt.value = string.gsub(clink.prompt.value, "{lamb}", "λ")
end

clink.prompt.register_filter(lambda_prompt_filter, 40)
```

These two scripts do not play very nicely with each other.  [Clink has an API](https://code.google.com/p/clink/wiki/Documentation) that seems like I could use to incorporate the change from `activate.bat`, but I cannot figure out how to call it from a batch file.

My overall goal is to merge these two prompts into the nicer Cmder-style.  My thought is to create an environment variable, change `activate.bat` to check for the existence of the variable, and, if so, call the Clink API to change the prompt instead of `set PROMPT`.  At that point I would think I could create a new filter to cleanly merge the value in.  I can't figure out how to call the API from the batch file, though.

Other solutions welcome.

EDIT: Partial, non-working solution

```
require "os" -- added to top of file, rest in filter function
local sub = os.getenv("CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV")
if sub == nil then
    sub = ""
end
print(sub)
clink.prompt.value = string.gsub(clink.prompt.value, "{conda}", sub)
```

I added a {conda} in the prompt definition at the very beginning; removed the prompt statement from `activate.bat`, and added this to `git_prompt_filter`.  Prior to using activate, everything is fine - the `{conda}` gets suppressed by the `''`.  However, if I use activate and switch into a folder with a git repo to trigger the change, I see:

`{conda}C:\...`

Does `os.getenv` not get user set variables?  Don't know what else the problem would be.  I also tried adding a print, it doesn't print out the contents of `CONDA...` either.

Comment: `os.getenv` is caching the value, use `clink.get_env`: https://github.com/mridgers/clink/blob/master/docs/api.md#clinkget_envenv_var_name

Answer (score 3):

This is what I do to reset the prompt and add the conda env name to the prompt:

```
---
 -- Find out the basename of a file/directory (last element after \ or /
 -- @return {basename}
---
function basename(inputstr)
        sep = "\\/"
        local last = nil
        local t={} ; i=1
        for str in string.gmatch(inputstr, "([^"..sep.."]+)") do
                --t[i] = str
                --i = i + 1
                last = str
        end
        return last
end

---
 -- Find out current conda env
 -- @return {false|conda env name}
---
function get_conda_env()
    env_path = clink.get_env('CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV')
    if env_path then
        basen = basename(env_path)
        return basen
    end
    return false
end

---
 -- after conda activate: reset prompt and add conda env name 
---
function conda_prompt_filter()
    -- reset to original, e.g. after conda activate destroyed it...
    if string.match(clink.prompt.value, "{lamb}") == nil then
        -- orig: $E[1;32;40m$P$S{git}{hg}$S$_$E[1;30;40m{lamb}$S$E[0m
        -- color codes: "\x1b[1;37;40m"
        cwd = clink.get_cwd()
        prompt = "\x1b[1;32;40m{cwd} {git}{hg} \n\x1b[1;30;40m{lamb} \x1b[0m"
        new_value = string.gsub(prompt, "{cwd}", cwd)
        clink.prompt.value = new_value
    end
    -- add in conda env name
    local conda_env = get_conda_env()
    if conda_env then
        clink.prompt.value = string.gsub(clink.prompt.value, "{lamb}", "["..conda_env.."] {lamb}")
    end
end

clink.prompt.register_filter(conda_prompt_filter, 10)
```

Answer (score 3):

I want to build on @Jan-Schulz answer since it didn't exactly work for me in April 2017.

1. Instead of editing `cmder/vendor/clink/clink.lua` I added custom code into `cmder/config/prompt.lua` which is not overwritten on upgrade (You can add additional modifications to cmder prompt in this file as well using the clink lua api)
2. I was having an issue where the `{lamb}` was not being replaced with the proper `λ` character so I added another filter to run at the end of all processing.

```lua
---
 -- Find out the basename of a file/directory (last element after \ or /
 -- @return {basename}
---
function basename(inputstr)
        sep = "\\/"
        local last = nil
        local t={} ; i=1
        for str in string.gmatch(inputstr, "([^"..sep.."]+)") do
                --t[i] = str
                --i = i + 1
                last = str
        end
        return last
end

---
 -- Find out current conda env
 -- @return {false|conda env name}
---
function get_conda_env()
    env_path = clink.get_env('CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV')
    if env_path then
        basen = basename(env_path)
        return basen
    end
    return false
end

---
 -- after conda activate: reset prompt and add conda env name 
---
function conda_prompt_filter()
    -- reset to original, e.g. after conda activate destroyed it...
    if string.match(clink.prompt.value, "{lamb}") == nil then
        -- orig: $E[1;32;40m$P$S{git}{hg}$S$_$E[1;30;40m{lamb}$S$E[0m
        -- color codes: "\x1b[1;37;40m"
        cwd = clink.get_cwd()
        prompt = "\x1b[1;32;40m{cwd} {git}{hg} \n\x1b[1;30;40m{lamb} \x1b[0m"
        new_value = string.gsub(prompt, "{cwd}", cwd)
        clink.prompt.value = new_value
    end
    -- add in conda env name
    local conda_env = get_conda_env()
    if conda_env then
        clink.prompt.value = string.gsub(clink.prompt.value, "{lamb}", "["..conda_env.."] {lamb}")
    end
end


function fix_lamb()
    if string.match(clink.prompt.value, "{lamb}") ~= nil then
        clink.prompt.value = string.gsub(clink.prompt.value, "{lamb}", "λ")
    end
end

clink.prompt.register_filter(conda_prompt_filter, 1)
clink.prompt.register_filter(fix_lamb, 999)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just delete the line from `activate.bat` and do all the logic in your cmder profile? CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV will be empty if no environment is active.

Comment: I was anticipating deleting that line from activate, but was trying to figure out how I (instead) call the Clink API from the batch file to let it know to update the prompt.  Are you suggesting to always cat in the CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV to the prompt?  I had thought the lambda_prompt_filter() was only called once to setup the prompt, but looking at again, it probably is being called every time a prompt is displayed.  Will investigate.

Comment: Even if it isn't setup every time, you should hopefully be able to get the environment variable to be dereferenced every time.

Comment: By the way, hopefully a future version of conda will use the changeps1 option on Windows like it does on OS X and Linux, allowing you to disable that line with a configuration setting. We don't have enough Windows experts to work on it to give it the love it deserves (but pull requests are welcome).

Comment: I've gotten this almost working, but os.getenv() in Lua on windows doesn't seem to get user-specific variables.  See above.